# Javascript/Jquery not working in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement this multi-select functionality (see link: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/318/) on my PHP page. I can get the table to display how I'd like, however, when I press the buttons to move the elements to either side nothing happens. The code works in the provided link but it doesn't work in my page, I was wondering why this is and if I'm missing anything such as AJAX. I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

Here's my HTML code:

```
<section class="container">
<div>
    <select id="leftValues" size="10" multiple>

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
</div>
<div>
    <select id="rightValues" size="10" multiple></select>
</div>
</section>
```

My Javascript/JQuery code:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
             var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
             $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);}
);

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
              var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
              $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});
}
</script>
</head>
```

CSS code:

```
SELECT, INPUT[type="text"] {
width: 250px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
SECTION {
width: 600px;
padding: 8px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
overflow: auto;
}
SECTION > DIV {
float: left;
padding: 4px;
}
SECTION > DIV + DIV {
width: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
```

I receive the following error in the console:

Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "handleEvent"' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)" location: "native frame ::  ::  :: line 0" data: no]

Comment: Not a debugging service.

Comment: Checked the console for errors? I also don't see how PHP nor AJAX figure into this.

Comment: When you run the page with PHP, are there any JS errors in the console? If there are, please add them to your question. If the JS is working in the fiddle, this sounds like there's some sort of minor syntax error somewhere. Probably no relation to AJAX.

Comment: When I checked the console this is the error that I recieved: Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "handleEvent"' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)" location: "native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0" data: no]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to do more debugging.

Try changing the buttons so that they `alert('something')` and if they don't alert anything then there is a bigger problem with the code....

**Hold on...**

I just did some searching on that error and came across this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449038

It seems like this error has nothing to do with your code.

---

I would try using a different browser just to test.

Comment: Thank you very much. It finally worked when I switched browsers from Firefox to Chrome. Also, I had to access the javascript file via HTTPS instead of HTTP so my new tag looked like this: <script src="https...</script> . Now I need to figure out how to get it working in Firefox as well

Comment: It was suggested that some extensions might be the issue ... Personally, I would remove/uninstall my extensions one by one to figure out which one may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly (for what you want).

There's just a small typo:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
             var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
             $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);}
);

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
              var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
              $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});
}
</script>
...
```

This is your script - to make it easier to spot:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   /*code to be executed */
}
</script>
...
```

Even simpler

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { /*code to be executed */ }
</script>
...
```

You are not closing the ready part that should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /*code to be executed */ });
```

So to keep the answer short (too late now probably), you're missing a `)`

The smallest problems are the hardest to find.

Use this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
             var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
             $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);}
);

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
              var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
              $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. However, the issue persists after making the proper edits.

Comment: check your console debug
I copy and pasted your code and that was the only change I had to make to get the desired result.

Comment: When I checked the console this is the error that I recieved: 
Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "handleEvent"' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0"  data: no]